# Mint function with 2 or 3 parameters Reverted

Tags: web3js, ether, ethereumjs, react

I am building a mint DAPP on the fantom blockchain.
However, when I call the mint function, it returns an error: (execution reverted: Invalid payment amount)

My React app communicates well with the smart contract since I can call the read functions and display them.
What I don't understand is that in the ABI and in the code the function takes 2 parameters. And in the smart contract it takes 3.

mint price: 20 ftm
amount : user choice, by default 1
stake (bool) : false

Here are all the screenshots to understand my code and smart contract : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjBtI.jpg

thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

The method is `paypable`. This is a Solidity identifier that indicates that you can send the native coin (e.g. ETH or BNB or FMT) along with the contract call. Therefore the blockexplorer shows an extra field to specify the amount.

Line 66 in your referenced contract checks if the correct value was sent along.

More info: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/cheatsheet.html?highlight=Payable#modifiers

Comment: const mintTxn = await contract.mint(qty, false, {value: ethers.utils.parseEther(nftPrice)});

Yes i add the price with parseEther function and now it works !